# Using dollar sign in sed for both variable replacement and character

Tags: bash, sed, escaping

I try to use sed to change a line in a file named convergence.gnu
I have a variable named `lafila`, which is a file name

Currently, I can do:

```
lafila="nGas060.dat"
sed -i "6s/.*/plot \"$lafila\" using 1:2 with l/" convergence.gnu
```

This changes correctly the sixth line of my convergence.gnu file to:

```
plot "nGas062.dat" using 1:2 with l
```

However, now I want to include a dollar sign in the replaced line to obtain instead:

```
plot "nGas062.dat" using ($1/1000):2 with l
```

Can you tell me what to change in my sed command? If I escape a dollar sign it does not work properly. Double dollars also don't work.

Comment: could you please add sample Input and expected output too? It will be good for all to understand the question.

Comment: Escaping the dollar sign with a backslash does work (`$ echo "\$PATH"
# prints $PATH`), so can you show us the exact command you tried and the result?

Comment: OK, I edited to make clear that in the sed I want to print a variable replacement first and then I want to print the dollar sign.

Comment: You can use the sed's `c` command to replace a line with specified text, which avoids having to worry about `/` characters in the replacement text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use single quotes:

```
sed -i '6s/.*/plot "'$lafila'" using ($1\/1000):2 with l/' convergence.gnu
```

Single quotes protect double quotes and `$` is not interpreted inside them.  However, you do need to escape `/`.

See also:

- [Difference between single and double quotes in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42082956/6862601)

Comment: But nGas062.dat is a variable named `$lafila`.
First I need the sed to replace $lafila and then to use the $1/1000

That is, if variable  `$lafila=nGas062.dat`
Then I need the output:
    `plot "nGas062.dat" using ($1/1000):2 with l`

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: **Perfect.** That one produced the expected result. Thanks!:
`sed -i '6s/.*/plot "'$lafilas'" using ($1\/1000):2 with l/' convergence.gnu`
Resulted in:
`plot "nGas060.dat" using ($1/1000):2 with l`

Answer (score 1):

I believe your issue is actually being caused by the forward slash in `($1/1000)`, which clashes with the slashes being used to delimit the various components of the sed command. You either need to escape that forward slash as well, or alternatively use a different character for delimiting the sed strings. Either of the below should work:

```
lafila="nGas060.dat"
sed -i "6s/.*/plot \"$lafila\" using (\$1\/1000):2 with l/" convergence.gnu
```

or

```
lafila="nGas060.dat"
sed -i "6s,.*,plot \"$lafila\" using (\$1/1000):2 with l," convergence.gnu
```

Using a different delimiting character can be a good way to make your sed string look neater and avoid the [leaning toothpick syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaning_toothpick_syndrome).

```
echo foo | sed "s,foo,/there/are/a/lot/of/slashes/here,"
```

is much nicer than

```
echo foo | sed "s/foo/\/there\/are\/a\/lot\/of\/slashes\/here/"
```

Comment: None of the commands given could read the `lafila` variable. First and second one resulted in: `plot "" using ($1/1000):2 with l` with empty space where `lafila` variable should be

Comment: That's just because I left out of the part where `lafila` was defined as I didn't think you had an issue with that section. I was just addressing the sed command that seemed to be giving you a problem. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
lafila="nGas060.dat"
sed -i "6s@.*@plot \"$lafila\" using (\\\$1/1000):2 with l@" convergence.gnu
```

You need only to escape backslash and after the dollar sign.

```
\\ + \$ == \\\$
```